# TestNG Listener onFinish(ITestContext context) can't get ThreadLocal instance (it returns null) BUT onTestFailure(ITestResult result) works fine

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146747/cant-able-to-take-screenshot-from-testnglistner-ontestfailure-method-when-ever) but it is not the same.

I use Selenium and TestNG to create a test.

I implemented TestNG Listerner, so in both test failure and test finish cases, I can grab Chrome browser log.

When I instantiate Chrome driver, I wrap it in a ThreadLocal , so I can use getter and setter when I want to use the instance.

TestNg listerner looks like this

```js
public class MyListeners extends TestBase implements ITestListener, ISuiteListener {

  @Override
  public void onStart(ISuite suite) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {

    //I set the attribute "browser" in @Test with value "chrome" so this following block will be run
    if (result.getAttribute("browser").equals("chrome")) {
      super.grablog(); //Works perfectly fine
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onStart(ITestContext context) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {

    int numberOfFailedTest = context.getFailedTests().size();

    if (numberOfFailedTest == 0) {
      //No Test Fails

      //Just a method to know which browser is used
      String usedBrowser = null;
      Set < ITestResult > passedTest = context.getPassedTests().getAllResults();
      Iterator < ITestResult > i = passedTest.iterator();
      if (i.hasNext()) {
        usedBrowser = i.next().getAttribute("browser").toString();
      }

      //I set the attribute "browser" in @Test with value "chrome" so this following block will be run
      if (usedBrowser.equals("chrome")) {
        super.grablog(); // Will not work
      }

    }
  }
}
```

This Listener class has super class TestBase which looks like this

```js
public class TestBase {

  public void initiate(String browser, String URL) throws InterruptedException {

    //Initiating Chrome Driver , usual standard procedur
    if (browser.equals("chrome")) {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\executeable\\chromedriver.exe");
      DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
      LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
      logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
      caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);

      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
      options.addArguments("start-maximized");

      options.merge(caps);
      driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }

    //Wrap the initiated driver to our local Thread
    DriverManager.setDriverThread(this.driver);
    DriverManager.getDriverThread().manage().window().maximize();
    DriverManager.getDriverThread().get(URL);
  }

  public void grablog() {
    Grablog grablog = new Grablog();
    grablog.grabbing();
  }

}
```

The Driver class to manage driver thread

```js
public class DriverManager {

  private static ThreadLocal < WebDriver > driverThread = new ThreadLocal < > ();

  public static WebDriver getDriverThread() {
    return driverThread.get();
  }

  public static void setDriverThread(WebDriver driver) {
    driverThread.set(driver);
  }
}
```

In my `@Test` class , I call the `initiate()` to initiate the Chrome browser `initiate("chrome", "www.website.com");` (otherwise, the browser won't start).

The confusing part is here.

```js
public class Grablog {

  //When TestNG Listener onFinish invoke this grabbing() , then new DriverManager().getDriverThread() will return null (bad)
  //When TestNG Listener onTestFailure invoke this grabbing() , then new DriverManager().getDriverThread() will return a driver instance (good)
  public void grabbing() {

    LogEntries logEntries = new DriverManager().getDriverThread().manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);

    //
    //Some codes here to save the log to a txt file
    //

  }
}
```

`new DriverManager().getDriverThread()` will return the driver instance when Listener `OnTestFailure()` is invoked (perfect, exactly what I want), but will return `null` when Listener `OnFinish()` is invoked (not what I want). I don't kill the driver instance (no `quit()` nor `close()` method used).

When all `@Test` finish successfully, Listener `OnFinish()` will be invoked,  No Exception thrown. No error message thrown. The test will finish with green tick. All green. But I don't get my log file. After some troubleshooting and running in debug mode , I found that the root cause was the driver instance is null. Why null?

I am wondering, why these 2 Listener methods works differently ?  I suspect, that when `OnFinish()` is invoked, all tests have been finished , thus all instances will be destroyed automatically by garbage collector? Can it be the reason?

I tried to put the `super.grablog()` in `public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result)` and it also works perfectly fine. Only `OnFinish()` works differently.

Is there any workaround solution for this particular issue? Or what could I potentially do wrongly?
In other post, someone suggested to initialize the driver in TestNG Listener. I might try that later , but I prefer to do that in my own class (rather than in Listener).  Thanks.

**UPDATE 7 Jan :**

I created a new class with one `@AfterSuite` method and moved the code block from `Listener OnFinish()` to that `@AfterSuite`. I listed the new class in my testng.xml, so it will be executed.

I encounter the same issue but this time `java.lang.NullPointerException` is thrown on exactly the same line caused by the same reason (`new DriverManager().getDriverThread()` returns null).